# Regex redundancy or extra security?

Tags: php, regex, security

Lets say i have a function that using regular expressions cleans a string:

```
function RegExCleaner($var)
{
    return preg_replace('Regular expression', '', $var)
}
```

Its not that important how the function looks and works. Just a simple example.

If i use this function to clean a user input or some value once, and then work with the value 'server-side' is it enough to clean it once or can i do it multi-layer? So if i use the variable in a sequence of functions, do i clean it in every function? Does this actually improve security or am i just adding non-necesary workload?

Comment: The purpose of sanitizing your inputs is so that you know that your inputs are what you expect them to be. If you check them once why would you do so more than once unless you are using the original variable multiple times? Check on the client side and check on the server then if you still have bad inputs you know you need to improve the checks being done.

Comment: Check client-side and server-side, and if you're paranoid, check one more time before storing in the database (or whatever the end-point is), and raise a debugging notice if the check is used, so you can investigate it if it ever triggers (it shouldn't).

Comment: Tnx, so basiclly checking (with a good method) client-side, server-side, and if/database right before input is quite enough security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two ways of handling user input:

1. **Sanitizing:** This removes unwanted stuff from the input. The unwanted stuff may be various tags, invalidly formatted characters, certain words or letters, etc. This is almost always something you should do. The only exception is if the input is a simple value such as an integer or a boolean value, which can be handled directly with validating.
2. **Validating:** This makes sure that the input is indeed what you expect it to be. Is it a number, boolean value, text blocks, etc.? This is not so much about security as it is about actually getting the right kind of data for your program to be able to function.

For both of these points there is a PHP extension called [Filter](http://php.net/filter). It was made with this stuff in mind.

For sanitizing input you could do something like this:

```
$name     = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$age      = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'age', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$email    = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password', FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW);
```

And for validating:

```
if (preg_match('/[\w\d]{4,20}/', $name) === 0) {
    die('Invalid name!');
}
if ( ! ctype_digit($age) || ($age < 13)) {
    die('Invalid age or too young!');
}
if ( ! filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    die('Invalid email address!');
}
if (strlen($password) < 10) {
    die('Password is too short!');
}
```

One very important thing to remember is that there is no magic pill. User input cannot just be washed in bleach as it comes in, and then be said to be safe. You need to know what the user input should be and then treat it accordingly. If it is not what you know it should be then hit the brakes immediately and throw it back at the user.

Comment: Thank you very much for your extensive answer!

Answer (score 1):

Better to have one place where this happens IMHO. Clean everything on the way into the system and then you have nothing to worry about later on. It can also get confusing to keep track of where you are sanitising stuff if you do it in lots of places. It won't hurt your logic to sanitise at every level, but it may make maintenance harder for this reason.

I'd recommend a library of functions to clean input, possibly wrapped in a class e.g. as static methods, and pass everything through one of those functions.

Comment: Tnx for the answer, yes im actually creating a library of that sorts.